# Aligning text on table using Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am currently learning how to use bootstrap and I am struggling with the following:
I created a simple table, but the information for an order I created will not align properly under the category.  Can somebody help?  I have provided a codepen link.

https://codepen.io/tacoholic/pen/LYYOrdb

HEre is how I have the HTML set up:

```
<h2>History</h2>
<div class="row">
<table class="table m-b-0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr class="black-cell">
            <th width="10%">Date <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></th>
            <th width="10%">Packages</th>
            <th width="10%">Tier</th>
            <th width="15%">Total</th>
            <th width="25%">Approval</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 border-right">
    <h3>
        <span class="m-l-40">05/26/2018 - 05-30-2018</span>
        <span class="m-l-120">234</span>
        <span class="m-l-120">Tier 4</span>
        <span class="m-l-120">$12.45</span>
        <span class="m-l-120">Approved</span>
    </h3>
    <div>
        <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you not using the table tbody to hold your data or create another h3 above the existing with the same spans and instead of the data replace with your header text

Comment: Your data should be inside the `<table><tbody></tbody></table>` markup.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `tbody` element with your `thead` element plus your `span` elements should be wrapped by a `tr` for the row and a `th` or `td` for the section.

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="black-cell">
        <th>Date <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></th>
        <th>Packages</th>
        <th>Tier</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Approval</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><span class="m-l-40">05/26/2018 - 05-30-2018</span></th>
      <td><span class="m-l-120">234</span></td>
      <td> <span class="m-l-120">Tier 4</span></td>
      <td> <span class="m-l-120">$12.45</span></td>
      <td> <span class="m-l-120">Approved</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not totally clear what your objective is, here is some sample code that uses the Bootstrap CDN. You need to make sure you're properly nesting columns in rows, and rows in tables.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Packages</th>
      <th scope="col">Tier</th>
      <th scope="col">Total</th>
      <th scope="col">Approval</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>05/26/2018 - 05-30-2018</td>
      <td>234</td>
      <td>Tier 4</td>
      <td>$12.45</td>
      <td>Approved</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

 <div>

<p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
</div>
```